# How do I use Excel.RangeAreas in Office JS?

Tags: excel, office-js, scriptlab

So I'm trying to use the RangeAreas class inside of Scriptlab to retrieve some information from multiple ranges at once, but I can't get it to work.
Here's my code:

```
$("#run").click(() => tryCatch(run));

async function run() {

  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var rangeAreas = sheet.getRanges("F3:F5, H3:H5");

    rangeAreas.load("address");

    await context.sync();

    console.log(rangeAreas.address);
  });
}

/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
async function tryCatch(callback) {
  try {
    await callback();
  } catch (error) {
    // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

And this is the error I get in Scriptlab's console:

```
c {name: "RichApi.Error", code: "InvalidArgument", traceMessages: Array[0], innerError: null, debugInfo: Object…}
 name: "RichApi.Error"
 code: "InvalidArgument"
 traceMessages: Array[0]
 innerError: null
▶debugInfo: Object
 code: "InvalidArgument"
 message: "L’argument est manquant ou non valide, ou a un format incorrect."
 toString: function ()
 errorLocation: "Worksheet.getRanges"
 statement: "var ranges=activeWorksheet.getRanges(...);"
▶surroundingStatements: Array[8]
 0: "var workbook=context.workbook;"
 1: "var worksheets=workbook.worksheets;"
 2: "var activeWorksheet=worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();"
 3: "// >>>>>"
 4: "var ranges=activeWorksheet.getRanges(...);"
 5: "// <<<<<"
 6: "// Instantiate {ranges}"
 7: "ranges.load(["address"]);"
▶fullStatements: Array[6]
 line: 24
 column: 243520
 sourceURL: "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-mac-16.00.js"
```

I'm sure I've made a silly mistake somewhere, but I just can't find where, and it's driving me mad. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs perfectly on my side. Is your system locale is in French? there is a known issue for the separator for the ranges, the separator changes based on system local.

So I guess in French it maybe uses ";", can you try the following code below?

```
var rangeAreas = sheet.getRanges("F3:F5; H3:H5");
```

Comment: My system is indeed in french and that snippet worked like a charm! Thanks!